# Unable to access formarray index when there is two category

Tags: angular

**Brief explaination**
I have two category.Category 1.Patients and it has index 0 to 8 and Category 2.Nurse and it has index 0 to 3. When i try to get the formarray index i only get category 1 index from 0 to 9 but i didnt get category 2 index 0 to 3.

**Code use to get index**

This code is used to get the formarray index but im unable to get the category 2 index 0 to 3.is there any way to get both the category index values.

```
onButtonClick(value:any, index:number):any{
    //debugger
    const formArray = this.patientPastHistoryForm.get("patientPastMedicalHistoryModelLists") as FormArray;
    ((this.patientPastHistoryForm.get('patientPastMedicalHistoryModelLists') as FormArray).at(index) as FormGroup).get('itemvalue').patchValue(value);
}
```

**my formbuilder code**

```
this.patientPastHistoryForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      patientID: new FormControl(this.clientId),
      phSubCatName: ['', Validators.required],
      patientPastMedicalHistoryModelLists: this.formBuilder.array([]),
```

Answer (score 0):

Hard to tell from with your brief information, sorry. Please provide more relevant code. `console.log()` the `value` and `index`.

Anyway `formArray` should hold a group of form control(s) which one of them is `itemvalue`. When patching the value on that control, we should also `updateValueAndValidity()` after patching a value for the patch to take effect.

```js
  onButtonClick(value:any, index:number): any {
    const formArray = (this.patientPastHistoryForm.get("patientPastMedicalHistoryModelLists") as FormArray);
    const group = (formArray.at(index) as FormGroup);
    group.get('itemvalue').patchValue(value);
    group.get('itemvalue').updateValueAndValidity();
   }
```

Comment: this code is getting only one array that is Category 1 but i have multiple arrays. After getting the first array it doesnt get the remaining array that is category 2 array. I ahave added my formbuilder code

Comment: my question is how to loop the form array elements to get all the values